# Enable NSCrossWebsiteTrackingUsageDescription programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14

Using **NSCrossWebsiteTrackingUsageDescription** in **info.plist** adds the option to the settings page for my application. My issue now is how do I either set this property to **enabled** or prompt the user with a dialogue box to enable/disable this feature?

Comment: There is no api to set or read this setting.